# jquery mobile .trigger('create') method doesn't work with iframe

Tags: jquery-mobile, triggers

When I try to `call .trigger('create')` method to iframe contents, it does not work and css classes are not applied to input:text elements.  but when I `call .trigger('create')` method for html content outside the iframe, it works. Here is my javascript code.

```html
     var content = ' <form class="fbm_contactform">\
        <div>Contact Us</div>\
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="name" >Name</label>\
        <input name="name" type="text" class="m-field" /></div>\
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="email">Email</label>\
        <input name="email" type="text" class="m-field" /></div>\
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label >Message</label>\
        <input name="message" type="text" class="m-field" /></div>\
        <input name="submitButton" type="submit" class="m-field" value="Send Message"  /></div>\
        </form> ';
    jQuery("#mobile_view").contents().find("#fbm_mob_menu").before(content);

    jQuery("#mobile_view").contents().find(".fbm_contactform").trigger("create");
    //console.log(jQuery("#mobile_view").contents().find(".fbm_contactform").html());
```

Console log prints the right html content.

Comment: show us your HTML..i dont think this is an iframe issue

Comment: this is my html, please go to this link [http://jsfiddle.net/m5maJ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/m5maJ/1/) on jsfiddle and click on "load mobile view"